# How to create popup image on top of other applications, while my application is running in the background?

Tags: android, ads

I have an Android application which in some stage run in the backgroung, and once some event happens, it takes over, and appears in the foreground.

now I want something more complex. when my activity is in the background, show small image at the bottom of the screen (like a popup ad), no matter what application is running. 
is this possible? (it's not the case of writing application, and letting ads engine to insert ads into my application. I want kind of opposite, without any integration)

Answer (score 1):

Like Jan said, you should be very careful with this as it can easily irritate users if not handled properly. Here is one way of showing a view overlay. You would need the owner of the phone to expressly grant you overlay permissions. You can then display views from a service class. You need to remember to handle the permissions correctly. You need to specify the following permission in your manifest -

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Because this is a dangerous permission, the user has to manually give you permission in settings. You can then in your service class work with windowManager to handle view alignment, size and details. For example -

```
windowManager = getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
        params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT)

        params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM
        if (view.windowToken != null) {
          try {
            windowManager!!.addView(view, params)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("The exception is", e.toString())
        }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but it is very much against the design principles of Android itself, and people will probaly remove your app instantly.